# Simple congruence relation (modular arithmetic)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, legendre-symbol

Let $p \neq 2,5$ be prime. Suppose you know that $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ and that $(\frac{p}{5}) = 1$, with $(\cdot)$ the Legendre Symbol.

How does it follow that $p \equiv 1 \mod 20 $ *or* that $p \equiv 9 \mod 20$?

Thanks!

EDIT: well, this is part of a larger question, this is the final part of my efforts, if I can solve this one, I solved the exercise. It's just an exercise found online, and I thought I could use this, for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$: $$(\frac{a}{q}) \equiv a^{(q-1)/2} \mod q,$$ with $q \neq 2$ prime. That gives you, combined with the fact that $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$, the solution $1  \mod 20$. I'm afraid I don't know how to obtain that $9 \mod 20$ though.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, at least your thoughts, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Comment: When is $\genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{p}{5} = 1$?

Comment: When $p^2 \equiv 1 \mod 5 $

Comment: And for what remainders modulo $5$ is that the case?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow? I know we have that $p \equiv 1 \mod 5$, is it that what you mean?

Comment: @querty $p^2\equiv 1\pmod{5}\iff p\equiv \{1,4\}\pmod{5}$.

Comment: Well, that explains why I was stuck. Thank you kindly!

Comment: @querty In general, $x^2\equiv a^2\pmod{p}$ always has exactly two solutions, namely $x\equiv \pm a\pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1^2\equiv \color{#00f}1,\, 2^2\equiv\color{#00f}4,\, 3^2\equiv\color{#00f}4,\, 4^2\equiv\color{#00f}1\pmod{5}$.

Therefore $\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)=1\iff p\equiv \{\color{#00f}1,\color{#00f}4\}\pmod{5}$.

It's given $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Now apply [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).